# Matching beginning for any capital lettters (Oracle)

Tags: regex, oracle

I m trying to match all the rows in a colum that start with any capital letters

I m trying

```
         SELECT Column
           FROM Table1
            WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (Column, '^[A-Z]');
```

but return all the values not only the thes who star with capitals letters

- I tryed differents variantes but nothing work for me.

cann enyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Enrique

Comment: may be somehow turn case sensitivity `REGEXP_LIKE (Column, '^[A-Z]', 'c');` on? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri excatly !!! thank you very very much , really it sound stupied but i lose like 2 hours doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
 REGEXP_LIKE (Column, '^[A-Z]', 'c')
```

or use between

```
WHERE ASCII(left(Column, 1)) between ASCII('A') and ASCII('Z')
```